# How to remove supercolumn using java/thrift

Tags: java, cassandra, thrift

Can anyone provide a clear example of how to remove a supercolumn in Java using thrift?

Edit: Found a solution, this allows me to delete any number of supercolumns that I want in one batch mutate.

```
    List<Mutation> mutations = new ArrayList<Mutation>();
    Map<String, List<Mutation>> keyMutations = new HashMap<String, List<Mutation>>();
    Map<ByteBuffer, Map<String, List<Mutation>>> mutationsMap = new HashMap<ByteBuffer, Map<String, List<Mutation>>>();
    try {
        tr.open();
        client.set_keyspace("my_keyspace");

        Deletion deletion = new Deletion();
        SlicePredicate slicePredicate = new SlicePredicate();

        List<ByteBuffer> columns = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();

        // Add as many supercolumns as you want here 
        columns.add(toByteBuffer("supercolumn_name"));

        slicePredicate.setColumn_names(columns);
        deletion.setPredicate(slicePredicate);

        // timestamp in microseconds        
        deletion.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000);

        Mutation m = new Mutation();
        m.setDeletion(deletion);

        mutations.add(m);

        keyMutations.put("column_family_name", mutations);

        mutationsMap.put(toByteBuffer("row_id_in_column_family"), keyMutations);
        client.batch_mutate(mutationsMap, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
         tr.flush();
         tr.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, this allows me to delete any number of supercolumns that I want in one batch mutate.

```
List<Mutation> mutations = new ArrayList<Mutation>();
Map<String, List<Mutation>> keyMutations = new HashMap<String, List<Mutation>>();
Map<ByteBuffer, Map<String, List<Mutation>>> mutationsMap = new HashMap<ByteBuffer, Map<String, List<Mutation>>>();
try {
    tr.open();
    client.set_keyspace("my_keyspace");

    Deletion deletion = new Deletion();
    SlicePredicate slicePredicate = new SlicePredicate();

    List<ByteBuffer> columns = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();

    // Add as many supercolumns as you want here 
    columns.add(toByteBuffer("supercolumn_name"));

    slicePredicate.setColumn_names(columns);
    deletion.setPredicate(slicePredicate);

    // timestamp in microseconds        
    deletion.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000);

    Mutation m = new Mutation();
    m.setDeletion(deletion);

    mutations.add(m);

    keyMutations.put("column_family_name", mutations);

    mutationsMap.put(toByteBuffer("row_id_in_column_family"), keyMutations);
    client.batch_mutate(mutationsMap, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
     tr.flush();
     tr.close();
}
```

Comment: right, rows delete is not a problem with Thrift, your question was how to drop the column family?, ok just saw your comment above, well in this case do like that, also all other client extend Thrift so deleting CF with  Thrift should be possible

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, I used also raw Thrift, but you should use a higher level [client](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions)

with Hector adding a CF is done like that:

```
String KEYSPACE = "Keyspace";
Cluster cluster = getOrCreateCluster("MyCluster", "127.0.0.1:9170");
CfDef cfDef = new CfDef(KEYSPACE, "Users").setComparator_type(BytesType.class.getSimpleName()).setKey_cache_size(0)
            .setRow_cache_size(0).setGc_grace_seconds(86400));

try {
    cluster.addColumnFamily(new ThriftCfDef(cfDef));
} catch (Throwable e) {
    logger.error("Exception while creating CF, " + cfDef.getName()
        + " - probably already exists", e);
    }
}
```

dropping is easier:

```
cluster.dropColumnFamily(KEYSPACE, "Users"); //with exceptions
```

[documentation](http://hector-client.github.com/hector//source/content/API/core/1.0-1/me/prettyprint/hector/api/Cluster.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck using thrift, I would definitely be using Hector if I could